# How to Display ListView elements in grid format

Tags: android, listview

I  need to display my listview elements in grid format. What steps can I follow?

Comment: Use GridView for this.and try to explain your question.

Comment: Its a better to use `GridView` which is default widget control of Android.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use one more technique GridView, a grid View contain inbuilt listview format only but it is having rows and columns, and better to go search Developer.android.com

Answer (score -1):

Use GridView for adapter settings like this 
ArrayAdapter adapter= new ArrayAdapter(context, xml in grid format, values); 
add to gridview to arrayadapter